# SQL. Как посчитать количество строк с нулевым значением (NULL)

Tags: sql

Подскажите правильный запрос в SQL, чтобы посчитать количество строк с нулевым значением NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, хоть ни разу и не оптимальный:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(someField) FROM someTable
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! все работает!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from Sometable
where SomeField is null
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как мне этот запрос добавить в более длинный запрос, где я не только считаю нули, но и строчки со значениями из нескольких соединенных таблиц

Comment: Запрос вида: SELECT Campaign, Budget_spent, count(*) AS "Number of users",  count([1 month later]) as "Number of paid users", 
FROM User_source 
JOIN Campaigns
ON replace((User_source.dump),'_','-') like ('%cpn-' || Campaigns.campaign_no || '%')
JOIN Payments
ON replace((User_source.dump),'_','-') like ('%-u' || Payments.user_id || '%')

Comment: когда использую WHERE  выдают синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: А что за ошибка?